# AVAudioSession deactivate while another session is running

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I have one audio session running in `playAndRecord` category and `mixWithOthers` option for a audio recorder. Let's call it `recordAudioSession`.

```
let recordAudioSession = AudioSession()
recordAudioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.mixWithOthers])
```

Also I have another audio session running in `playback` category and `mixWithOthers` option for playing audio stream. Let's call it `playAudioSession`.

```
let playAudioSession= AudioSession()
playAudioSession.setCategory(.playback, options: [.mixWithOthers])
```

I have one audio is playing through my `playAudioSession` using an AVAudioPlayer, at the same time there is a recorder is running through my `recordAudioSession` trying to record the audio.

Now, once audio finishes playing, I try to deactivate `playAudioSession`, but leave `recordAudioSession` alive:

```
audioPlayer.stop()
playAudioSession.setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
```

So basically, One session finishes its task and I want to deactivate, the other one is still in use, so I want to keep it working.

But I'm getting an error log, and my recorder getting closed by system:

```
AVAudioSession.mm:692: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running i/o. all i/o should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.
```

Is this error means any audio session cannot be running I/O while deactivating an audio session, or I'm doing it in an incorrect way?

Is there any way that I can keep that recorder reading and deactivate the `playAudioSession`?